# Declaring mysql variables inside a heidisql query tab

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I have declared a variable in a heidisql tab like this

```
DECLARE total_count INT DEFAULT 0;
SET total_count = 10;
select total_count;
```

but i get this error

> /* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECLARE total_count INT DEFAULT 0' at line 1 */ /*
>   Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0 of 3
>   queries: 0.000 sec. */

Should i be declaring ,setting and using the variable like i have done or must i wrap everything inside a stored procedure or a function?.

Comment: I see you are using dummy column. If you declare you do not need set. Either way works.  Then check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b97db/11

Comment: The declare part needs to be dropped since you are using `@` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b97db/16

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
SET @total_count := 10;
select @total_count;
```

Comment: The colon isn't necessary. You can do `SET @total_count = 10;`

Answer (score 2):

Dropping the semicolons worked for me, in version 8.2.0, alas with MS SQL 2008

```
DECLARE @total_count INT
SET @total_count = 10
SELECT total_count
```